# How to fix NetworkOnMainThreadException when sending an image file

Tags: java, android, image, sockets

Acually I try to send an image file from Android to another computer, but I got an error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

```
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): Process: com.example.singh, PID: 1201
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.example.singh.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-08 00:57:40.474: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 00:57:42.944: I/Process(1201): Sending signal. PID: 1201 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You are doing your network operation on main thread. do it on seperate thread like async etc\

Comment: Run your code in AsyncTask

Comment: Use async task, Add this code to your activity   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 }

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send/upload image on main thread. You should do it in background thread. You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for the purpose.

Android docs:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).